Why does choosing the app as the default launcher create a new activity without destroying the current one?
I'm encountering an unexpected behavior in my Android app where selecting the app as the default launcher leads to the creation of a new activity instance without destroying the current one.
My MainActivity doesn't call onDestroy at all.
Upon further investigation, I've noticed that certain functions in my helper classes, which are instantiated within MainActivity, are being invoked with two instances of those helper classes. This observation coincides with the discovery of two activity instances.
My MainActivity manifest:
        <activity
            android:name=".presentation.MainActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:resizeableActivity="true"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="metanode" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    ```


Is it just me. But I dont understand what is it that you are trying to ask, can you improve your question

i just add more detail ...

maybe my only way to find a way to deal with 2 activity instances

I'm assuming you need those intent filters but check
1.If you're using Android 12 and above pressing back puts your activity in the background rather than destroying it
2.Your intent flags being used, they can destroy existing instances of activities in your task
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#ManagingTasks
